# Proper way to sleep during a lock with await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, httpclient, async-await

In my win8 (winrt, c#) application, I need to call a web API which has a very specific limitation:  No more one call to the web service every 2 seconds.

I've attempted to enforce this limit, like so:

```
class Client
{
    const int Delay = 2000;
    HttpClient m_client = new HttpClient();
    int m_ticks = 0;

    public async Task<string> Get(string url)
    {
        // Multiple threads could be calling, I need to protect access to m_ticks:
        string result = null;
        lock (this)
        {
            int ticks = Environment.TickCount - m_ticks;
            if (ticks < Delay)
                await Task.Delay(Delay - ticks);

            result = await m_client.GetStringAsync(url);

            m_ticks = Environment.TickCount;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This has run me into a brick wall:

1. I cannot use the await statement in a lock.
2. I cannot fall back to something like WebClient + Thread.Sleep (avoiding the async nonsense) because it doesn't exist in the win8 client profile.
3. I cannot avoid this method being "async" because then I cannot await GetStringAsync or Task.Delay without being in an async function.
4. I cannot avoid the lock, because multiple threads could be calling into this function, and I need synchronous access to m_ticks.

How in the world would I go about writing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

Use a Concurent queue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

All the requests to use the web service will be added to the queue.

You will have a thread that will enqueue one object every two seconds use it and return the answer.

Comment: Inelegant, but effective I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

The [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) type was extended in .NET 4.5 to include `await`-compatible `WaitAsync` methods. It doesn't have an `IDisposable`-based `Release`, but it's not hard to build one:

```
sealed class SemaphoreSlimReleaser : IDisposable
{
  SemaphoreSlim mutex;
  public SemaphoreSlimReleaser(SemaphoreSlim mutex)
  {
    this.mutex = mutex;
  }

  void Dispose()
  {
    if (mutex == null)
      return;
    mutex.Release();
    mutex = null;
  }
}
```

Then you can use code very similar to what you already have:

```
class Client
{
  const int Delay = 2000;
  HttpClient m_client = new HttpClient();
  int m_ticks = 0;
  SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

  public async Task<string> Get(string url)
  {
    // Multiple threads could be calling, I need to protect access to m_ticks:
    string result = null;
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    using (new SemaphoreSlimReleaser(mutex))
    {
        int ticks = Environment.TickCount - m_ticks;
        if (ticks < Delay)
            await Task.Delay(Delay - ticks);

        result = await m_client.GetStringAsync(url);

        m_ticks = Environment.TickCount;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

P.S. If you're interested, my AsyncEx library has a [full suite of `async`-compatible synchronization primitives](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/documentation) inspired by [Stephen Toub's blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you set the `mutex` to null on `Dispose`? What if you want to reuse the `SemaphoreSlim` for other concurrent operations?

Comment: @TopinFrassi: the `SemaphoreSlimReleaser` just represents a single "acquire/release" on that semaphore, not the semaphore itself. I'm setting the member variable to `null` so that multiple disposals have no effect.